# CSS - filter: alpha only for parent, not for children

Tags: css, filter, alpha

I'm trying to create an alert message box in html/css.

Here is my code:

```
        <div class="dim" id="msg">
            <div class="dialog_wrapper">
                <div class="dialog" id="msg_value"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
.dim
{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    position:fixed;
    left:0;
    display: none;
    top:0;
    z-index:1 !important;
    background-color:black;
    filter: alpha(opacity=75); /* internet explorer */
    -khtml-opacity: 0.75;      /* khtml, old safari */
    -moz-opacity: 0.75;       /* mozilla, netscape */
    opacity: 0.75;           /* fx, safari, opera */
}

.dialog_wrapper { opacity: 1; -moz-opacity: 1; -khtml-opacity: 1; filter: alpha(opacity=100); width: 100%; top: 40%; left: 0px; position: absolute; z-index: 5; display: block;  }
.dialog { opacity: 1; -moz-opacity: 1; -khtml-opacity: 1; filter: alpha(opacity=100); width: 400px; height: 10%; margin: 0 auto; padding: 40px; background-color: #fff; border: 1px solid #ccc; color: #333; }
```

The problem is filter:aplha. This filter is using with background and with message box too. I wouldn't use this filter for message box, only for background.

How I can do it?

Thanks.

Comment: what is message box in your code?

Comment: It's a div which contain an message text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply set `rgba` background-color to your `.dim`

```
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
```

***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/hiseca/2/edit?html,css,output)***